# Textlinemetrics : Finding the exact X of first character

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a challenge to left align text in different textfields with different fonts. I'm using textlinemetrics but can't figure out how to use it properly:(

The actionscript code is posted below.

What I have now is this:

screenshot of my result so far:
[image]

Now my goal would be:

finding the X and aligning the text:
[image]

Thanks for reading :)

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.text.*;
import flash.events.*

public class TextMetrics extends MovieClip {

    var metrics1:TextLineMetrics;
    var metrics2:TextLineMetrics;

    public function TextMetrics() {

        txtInput1.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, fncDisplayText);
        txtInput2.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, fncDisplayText);

    }

    private function fncDisplayText(e:Event){

        txtOutput1.text = txtInput1.text;           // display input text
        txtOutput2.text = txtInput2.text;

        metrics1 = txtOutput1.getLineMetrics(0);    // get metrics from first character, index 0
        mcX1.x = metrics1.x;// + txtOutput1.x;

        metrics2 = txtOutput2.getLineMetrics(0);
        mcX2.x = metrics2.x;// + txtOutput2.x;
    }

   }    //end public class
}   //end package
```

Comment: Rather than metrics, why don't you use a more suitable method? https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#getCharBoundaries()

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion !
It works good enough for now, ust a few pixels off.
I'll try to explore an exact solution later.

Comment: There's also margins of the **TextField**, or maybe **scrollV** and **scrollH** properties affects the result.

Comment: Well, I'm using getCharBoudaries now and it works fine. However, it took some headbanging :) I got "null" results sometimes until I realized I did not embed the font. So embedding the font i spretty important.